# Cocoa NSRect OUTSIDE of an intersection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, intersection, rect

I have two rects that intersect. They have the same dimensions, the only difference is that one of them is lower down the screen than the other. I know there is a way to get the rect of their intersection, but that's not what I want. I actually want a new rect from the area that lies outside of their intersection.

The top part of the lower view intersects with the bottom part of the top view. The new rect should not have that area. I basically want a rect with the same origin and width as the bottom view, but without the part that intersects with the top rect.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use simple arithmetic and calculate it?

Comment: That's what I first thought. I'm just wondering if cocoa provided a better way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGRect intersectRect = CGRectIntersection(highestRect, lowestRect);

CGRect theRectYouWant = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

if(!CGRectIsNull(intersectRect)) {
    theRectYouWant = 
        CGRectMake(lowestRect.origin.x,
                   intersectRect.origin.y + intersectRect.size.height,
                   lowestRect.size.width,
                   lowestRect.size.height - intersectRect.size.height);
}
```

Have a look on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) page for more, Elbimio ;)